# Storing a value of a function in a vector in R programming

Tags: r, function, vector

I'm new to R and I'm trying to store the value of the following function inside a vector in r.
**f(x) = 0.1e^x . cosx + 2ln|x|**
and I want to find the summation of this function when x = (2,2.1,2.2,...)
my code so far is the following:

```
           VecA <- c(function(x){
           0.1*exp(x)*cos(x)+2*log(|x|)
            })
```

Can someone please help me with this. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Maybe `VecA <- 0.1*exp(x)*cos(x)+2*log(abs(x))` ?

Answer (score 0):

I write the function as follows:

```
VecA <- function(x){
  0.1*exp(x)*cos(x)+2*log(abs(x))
}
```

I set values in vector:

`x = c(2,2.1,2.2)`

Finally, I find the summation of these values:

`sum(VecA(x))`

#Output:
`[1] 3.196202`